# Python split '123' into '1', '2', '3'

Tags: python

My program takes a user input such as:

```
>>> x = input()
>>> 1
>>> print x
>>> one
```

my actual code:

```
>>> import string
>>> numbers = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
>>> wordNumbers = ['zero', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine']
>>> myDict = dict(zip(numbers, wordNumbers))
>>> myVar = (raw_input("Enter a number to be tranlated: "))

>>> for translate in myVar.split():
>>>     print(myDict[translate])
```

The problem is I need the user to input `123` and for my program to output `one two three`, but it doesn't for some reason.

I'm thinking that if I add spaces with some syntax between `123` like `1 2 3` it would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You simply need to use:

```
for translate in myVar:
```

Instead of:

```
for translate in myVar.split():
```

Iterating over a string gives you its characters one by one, which is what you need.

If you do want to convert `'123'` to `'1 2 3'` (which isn't needed here because you don't need to use `split`), you can use:

```
' '.join(myVar)
```

Comment: This will work if myVar is entered as '123'. If myVar is 123, the loop shoud iterate over str(myVar). Right?

Comment: @IRO-bot: Since he used `raw_input`, `myVar` will always be a string. If it was an integer then you'd need `str(myVar)`.